# How to Connect Scanner device with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to connect Scanner device with Angular application. I have Scanner page where user can see Scanner Connection Alert and scanned documents, if user scan the document means it should display at browser not a local. Please let me know how to connect with scanner and get scanned copy at browser But I want a Open source not a paid version.

Comment: please give some more context, what do you mean by Scanner? a physical scanner/printer device?

Answer (score -1):

To connect a scanner device with an Angular application, you can use a JavaScript library such as "javascript-scan-sdk" or "dynamsoft-javascript-barcode".

[dynamsoft-javascript-barcode](https://www.dynamsoft.com/barcode-reader/docs/web/programming/javascript/samples-demos/HelloWorld-angular.html?ver=latest)

the above link has the complete details about the scanning

Comment: Thanks for your response, I checked these SDK  but its not a open source. I don't want to use paid version.

Comment: did you use ngx scanner. package is an open source and there also updates

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zxing/ngx-scanner

Comment: I will check, Actually I need to connect physical document scanner to browser and ngx-scanner is based on QR code scanner but I will try to connect.